# When date field is empty gate null result

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have 3 fields

1. Sign in date and time
2. Sign out out date and time
3. Total calculated time

Here is the formula I used

`=IF(ISBLANK([CHeck-out]), "" , TEXT[Check-out]-[check-in],"h: mm")`

I want a field to be null when check-out field date is empty. I found some answers but keep giving me an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer below Formula :

```
=IF([Check-out]="","",(TEXT([Check-out]-[Check-in],"h:mm")))
```

**Here if the `Check-out` field will be empty, it will direct return empty.**

**But if `Check-out` field is non-empty, it will go ahead and find the difference between `Check-out` and `Check-in` field and return the date/time in specified format.**

Comment: I tried your formula with different data types, it keeps giving me error message

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by different data type....because this works perfectly for date time field........

Comment: Sorry Rohit, I should clarified better. I mean to say the data type returned from this formula( I tried with TEXT, NUMBER and DATE and TIME)

Comment: You mean to say data type for calculated field.. Am I right?

Comment: Rohit, it works perfectly sorry I was missing a bracket. Do you know how I can display the result on a SharePoint new form which is customized by infopath. Let's say I inter time in and time out and the total calculated hour should be available before I save the form. Currently I can only see the result after I save and close the form on edit form and view form. I will mark the previous answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry man. I have no idea about that ..

Answer (score 0):

Use condition operator

```
Newdate=date?date:"";
```

Using this you can get where it is emplty or not and not shows error.